# Hang in [NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer]

Tags: nsopenglview

I have two NSOpenGLViews, named myView1 and myView2. myView2 is a sub view of myView1. Then I use *CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay* to create a display link for the main display. Both myView1 and myView2 will draw something in the main thread(i.e. in *drawRect* function) using OpenGL. In the display link callback, I'll also draw something for myView1 using OpenGL.

The drawing codes is something like

```
[self.openGLContext makeCurrentContext];
[self.openGLContext lock];

//draw something ...

[self.openGLContext flushBuffer];
[self.openGLContext unlock];
```

Everything works well at this moment. But if I add the following code for both myView1 and myView2, it will easily runs into a hang.

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

The call stack is here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOvwr.png)

It seems that both the main thread and Display Link callback locks in [NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer].
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to be the relevant radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/37064579